# ESTA - Point of Contact and Personal Address

Tags: usa, esta, new-york-city, airbnb

In two months I am going to be in NY again for tourism and since my prevuious ESTA expired, I need to reapply for a new one.
This time, I am gonna stay in an AirBnB but I don't have the family name of the host, just her given name, to put it into the US Point of Contact Info. Do you think it would be ok if I used the name of the place I am gonna stay in as called on Airbnb "The Small Place in NY" or just the given name of the host, and her mobile number?
Also, I am not sure of what to put on my personal address information, as city where I work and live in is different from my residential address.

Could someone help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: you can always change the address, when you get ESTA. Just put an address. In any case, I do not understand what it is the second problem. Many people works in different cities (and in Europe, maybe in different countries), and I never had problem on interpreting ESTA. So could you share more about your specific problem?

Comment: Hi Giacomo, thank you for your reply. 
Regarding the first question, do you think I can use only the name of the host without the surname as my point of contact? 
Regarding the second, I basically work in a city which is different from the city where I was born and that is indicated in my passport, so I was wondering what address should I put

Comment: 1- Put the address of your AirBnB. They need just it. 2- it is not a problem. Passport is not about recording where you work (or you live). It is normal (and very common) to live and work in different cities/towns. And it is also not a problem to work in a different country. And that it is not a fact that should be on your passport (which it is a travel document).